# How do I change the border of a TButton using ttk Style?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I want to define a ttk Style for TButton that sets a thick black border around it.

This code I wrote seems to have no effect on the TButton border:

```
root = tk.Tk()

my_style = ttk.Style()
my_style.configure('my_style.TButton',
    width=10,
    height=20,
    wraplength=150,
    justify='center',
    font=('Arial', 20),
    borderwidth=10,
    bordercolor='#000000')
button = ttk.Button(root, text="Click me", style='my_style.TButton')
button.pack()
```

How can I achieve getting a thick border around the TButton?

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of how it looks like for you and describe how you want the border to look like? Because the border looks thick in my opinion (screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/FHeErNH).

Comment: So this is what I'm seeing right now: https://imgur.com/a/cwvUrND

And this is what I'd like to achieve: https://imgur.com/a/filA7TY

Comment: Try setting the theme by putting `my_style.theme_use('default')` BEFORE `my_style.configure(...)`